# Algorithm to find smallest set of objects with a total combined value bewteen X and Y

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a set of Objects (around a 100), and each one has a float value (realistically from -10000 to 10000, but let's assume there are no limits).

My objective is to find the smallest set of those objects (as few as possible) of which the total combined value would be between variables X and Y.

I believe I could tackle this task with some Evolutionary Algorithms, but I was wondering if there was a simpler mathematical solution to this?

I am programming in PHP, but I don't believe that's relevant and I could use any ideas on algorithm/pseudocode.

Thank you!

Comment: php? sounds like an odd choice

Comment: It's not the choice for this particular task, it's this task that is something I need to achieve within my php application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem looks like a variant of [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). There is no easy way of solving this problem on a scale - bruteforce will work with the smallest instances. For moderatly large problems you can use [dynamic programming](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/). In general, you might be using [mixed integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming), various [metaheuristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaheuristic) or [constraint satisfaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem).

To my opinion, the last one should be the best for you, for example, consider [Minizinc](http://www.minizinc.org/). It is really easy to use and it's quite efficient in terms of runtime/memory consumption.  For example, consider [this](https://github.com/MiniZinc/minizinc-examples/blob/master/knapsack/knapsack.mzn) example of solving knapsack problem.

So you can just generate textual representation of your problem, feed it to Minizinc and read back the solutions.

Comment: Thank you, this pretty much answered my question that there is no easy mathematical solution. I will take a look at your suggestions. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Using Python you can safely go for the route of combinations.

Combinations are iterables: each time you iterate on a combination it returns you a unique set of objects.

You can start with sets of very low sizes (2, 3, 4 objects...) and then perform a sum of the values and make your check.

To perform a sum of the values I would recommend you take a look at numpy.arrays, they will speed up the process.

In behind, combinations use factorial arithmetics, this means nearly exponential number of possible combinations the larger your combination is.

More info:

[Numpy Array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)

[Itertools Combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

This will end in a bruteforce for which you can expect to check for thousands of combinations per seconds. I don't know if that's the best algorithm, but it is simple and it works.

**Example code:**

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy

a = [1,-2,3,-4,5,-6,7,-8] # Any list of float or integers...
min = 5
max = 10
size = 3
c = combinations(a, size)
for combi in c:
 a = numpy.array(combi)
 if (a.sum() in range(min, max)):
  print('Result found for '+str(combi))
  break
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If there isn't a more elegant mathematical solution to this problem, then I would probably rather go down Evolutionary Algorithms route (like a simple ACO) rather than simple brute force.

Comment: I added an example, might be useful for somebody else.